# c getprotobyname getting protocols information

Tags: c, network-programming

Im just starting to learn C programming and for exercise i found this task. First i have to scan in name of a protocol. Then i have to check official name, number and alias of a protocol. So if i enter tcp the output would look like this:
official name: tcp
proto number: 6
alias TCP

This is what i've got so far. When i run it and enter ip or tcp it doesn't give me any errors. But it says that the protocol not found.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    char  name[200];
    int i;

    struct protoent *proto = getprotobyname(name);

    printf("Enter protocol name: ");        
    scanf("%c", name);

    proto = getprotobyname( name );  


    if ( proto != NULL )
    {
        printf("official name: %s\n", proto->p_name);

        printf("proto number: %d\n", proto->p_proto);

        for ( i = 0; proto->p_aliases[i] != 0; i++ ){
                 printf("alias: %s\n", proto->p_aliases[i]);
            }
    }
    else{
        perror("protocol not found");
    }


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bug 1: `getprotobyname(name);` is called two time one is before`name` initialized and second is after it.and Bug 2: `scanf("%c", name);` must be `scanf("%s", name);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 char  name[200];
 int i;
 struct protoent *proto = getprotobyname(name);
```

Here `name` is utilized and after that you read `name` by

```
 scanf("%c", name);
```

This is also wrong to read char array. Require `%s` format specifier to read char array. So it should be

```
 scanf("%s", name);
```

Your code should be

```
int main(){
    char  name[200];
    int i;

    struct protoent *proto;

    printf("Enter protocol name: ");        
    scanf("%s", name);

    proto = getprotobyname( name );  


    if ( proto != NULL )
    {
        printf("official name: %s\n", proto->p_name);

        printf("proto number: %d\n", proto->p_proto);

        for ( i = 0; proto->p_aliases[i] != 0; i++ ){
                 printf("alias: %s\n", proto->p_aliases[i]);
            }
    }
    else{
        perror("protocol not found");
    }


        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the bug: `scanf("%c", name);`

You're are just reading one single character by passing format specifier to `scanf` with `%c`. With this `getprotobyname()` returns an invalid, hence you see the print `protocol not found`.

Instead you need to read entire string from stdin by using `%s`.